# cannot read property 'createResolver' of undefined

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

C:\Users\VM-OUT-Kramar-YA_ALL\OPERATION\bfs-bvfo-br-pl\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:373

```
throw e;
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'createResolver' of undefined

at WebpackOptionsApply.process (C:\Users\VM-OUT-Kramar-YA_ALL\OPERATION\bfs-bvfo-br-pl\node_modules\webpack\lib\WebpackOptionsApply.js:283:46)

at webpack (C:\Users\VM-OUT-Kramar-YA_ALL\OPERATION\bfs-bvfo-br-pl\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:37:48)

at startDevServer (C:\Users\VM-OUT-Kramar-YA_ALL\OPERATION\bfs-bvfo-br-pl\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:367:16)

at processOptions (C:\Users\VM-OUT-Kramar-YA_ALL\OPERATION\bfs-bvfo-br-pl\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:350:5)

at Object. (C:\Users\VM-OUT-Kramar-YA_ALL\OPERATION\bfs-bvfo-br-pl\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:495:1)

at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)

at Module.load (module.js:488:32)

at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)

at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)

at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)

at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)

at startup (bootstrap_node.js:151:9)

at bootstrap_node.js:542:3

Versions:
"webpack": "3.10.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "2.11.2",